# Where can I look up voting guide for better bike infrastructure?

Tags: bikeroutes, advocacy

All I care about (my #1 issue) is getting better separated bicycle infrastructure (kid, old-person etc friendly) to southern California. Specifically for upcoming election and especially for local city election for a southern California city ([Dana Point, CA](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Dana+Point,+CA&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=Dana+Point,+CA&gl=us&ei=HHiwTLKUFoT48AbehNGdCQ&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=image&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ8gEwAA)) where can I look up who to vote for?

Something like the Sierra Club voting guide, but from bicyclist's perspective and especially for local politics. Other elections in addition to city council could be relevant also, state and federal as well as offices like the Sheriff.

Comment: This question is quite regional, but I suspect that the underlying principles will be of use for people in other areas -- e.g., the kinds of resources to look for, what questions to ask, et cetera.

Answer (score 7):

The closest thing I know of nationally is the League of American Bicyclists [I Bike - I Vote](http://www.bikeleague.org/programs/bikeadvocacy/election.php) page, but that is not going to really give you a clue about for whom you should vote. It's more a resource for issues before Congress that you could use to question candidates.

I don't know where Dana Point is, but I know many counties in CA have bicycle advocacy groups like the [Los Angeles County Bicycle Coalition](http://la-bike.org/).  Here's a page with links to other [CA Bike Advocacy Groups](http://www.calbike.org/about/local-affiliates/).  Your best bet is to contact your local group and talk to them about issues and recommendations. While you are at it, join, donate and become active. Like stated in [this post on bicycling advocacy](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/856/what-are-the-most-effective-methods-of-bicycling-advocacy), the best way to be involved is to be active locally.

Comment: Looks to me like Dana Point is at the southern end of Orange County, so: http://ocbike.org/.

Comment: +1 for mentioning local bicycle coalition. Note that many bicycle coalitions have a non-profit status that allows them to *educate* but not *advocate* when it comes to specific issues or candidates on the ballot.  For instance, in previous years, my local bicycle coalition has sent questionnaires to local candidates and posted their answer, but doesn't comment.  Best bet might be to to chat with one of them "off the record", or read between the lines a bit...

Comment: Thanks, " educate but not advocate " explains alot, ocbike doesn't seem to have any voting type info, but I'll see what I can figure out from there.